# Laravel 5.2 Auth with TwigBridge Session store not set

Tags: php, laravel, twig, laravel-5

As mentioned in the title I'm using Laravel 5.2 and I've set up TwigBridge so I can use twig for my views. I'm just using the basic Auth package that comes with Laravel. The problem is when I use twig templates I get the following error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Session store not set on request.") in "...resources/views/auth/register.twig" at line 17.
```

This is pointing to a use of the `{{ old('name') }}` call. I've tried switching it to `input_old` as I think TwigBridge prefers that, but that didn't help. If I use the blade template there's no problem though. I'm not doing anything special either. I just rename the blade template so it isn't called, and my register twig template is called instead since it uses the name `register`.

Comment: do these routes have the 'web' middleware applied?

Comment: I haven't applied it, but that's why I'm confused. They are added to the routes.php file by simply putting `Routes::auth()`. Doing this causes no problems when I'm using the normal blade templates. The problem occurs when using my Twig templates.

Answer (score 0):

The old values are fetch from the session. To get these values to store in session & fetch these values back, you need to apply `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession` and 
 `\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession` middlewares to your routes. Both of these are a part of middleware group `web`.

You can apply `web` middleware group to all your routes(unless you are creating an API), like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::get("login" , "AuthController@getLogin");

    //Similarly all other routes here
});
```

Comment: As I mentioned above this shouldn't be an issue. The authentication routes are added the same way as in this tutorial: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart-intermediate#authentication-routing. This works without having to add anything to the web middleware group if I use the default auth blade templates. It is only a problem when I switch to using my own custom twig templates.

Comment: I was just giving you an example by using authentication routes, you should add all routes inside the web middleware group, not just authentication routes. Try this once, especially for routes on which you are using twig templates.

Comment: Thanks. I think I've actually found a bigger problem. TwigBridge apparently doesn't support middleware groups. Whenever I put routes that use TwigBridge into a middleware group it causes a nesting function call error. So, I'll just not be using 5.2. Thanks again though.